# Ultrafilter bounded convergent to 0 sequences

Tags: convergence-divergence, filters

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a free ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$. It is known that every bounded sequence $x$ is $\mathscr{F}$-convergent. Hence the space of bounded $\mathscr{F}$-convergent sequences is equal to $\ell_\infty$.

Is there something interesting about the space of bounded sequences which are $\mathscr{F}$-convergent to $0$?

I know it is a vague question, but I cannot find any interesting property.

Comment: Well, what do you want to know about this space?  It doesn't really have any simpler description than the one you gave...

Comment: If you are talking about Banach limits, and if the sequences are nonnegative, then a Banach limit of 0 means the usual limit is also 0. If you are just dealing with any (possibly negative) bounded sequence, then $\{b_n\}$ has a Banach limit of $\theta$ if and only if $\{b_n - \theta\}$ has a Banach limit of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this space is a (non-unital) commutative C*-algebra so one way to understand it is using its spectrum.  The spectrum of $\ell^\infty$ is $\beta\mathbb{N}$, the space of ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$ (considering each ultrafilter as the character $\ell^\infty\to\mathbb{C}$ sending a sequence to its limit with respect to the ultrafilter.  So $\ell^\infty\cong C(\beta\mathbb{N})$, and then your subspace is just the ideal of elements which vanish at the ultrafilter $\mathscr{F}$.  That is, its spectrum is $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\{\mathscr{F}\}$ and it is isomorphic to $C_0(\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\{\mathscr{F}\})$, the algebra of continuous functions on the locally compact Hausdorff space $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\{\mathscr{F}\}$ which vanish at infinity.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your answer. However, I am aware of what is a spectrum of a continuous linear operator. But what do you mean by spectrum of $\ell^\infty$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation#The_spectrum_of_a_commutative_C*-algebra